# Why I got wrong outputs for converting RGB to l*a*b* color values using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure

I have an image with green background and some shadows around my materials(some pieces of pumpkin). I want to remove background and shadows and then convert RGB color to l*a*b* and separate l*, a*, b*. finally get mean of l*,a*,b* values.these are my codes:

```
I=imread('006.jpg');   %import image
I=double(I)./255;   %convert to double
I=imresize(I,0.25);    %resize image
G=I(:,:,2)-I(:,:,1)-I(:,:,3);   %how green(2) compared to red(1) and blue(3)
L=I.*repmat(G < 0,[1,1,3]);   %remove all values that are green
%convert rgb to lab
L=makecform('srgb2lab');
lab=applycform(I,L); 
%separate l, a, b values
l=lab(:,:,1);
a=lab(:,:,2);
b=lab(:,:,3);
%calculate mean values
lm=mean(mean(l));
am=mean(mean(a));
bm=mean(mean(b));
```

At the end, these codes give me l=82, a=-31, b=78.
but they are wrong, because I check the range of these values with digital color meter and they should be approximately like l=70 , a=17, b=66. I think these codes show the lab values of background that I've removed instead of the lab values of materials!!!!
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have MATLAB > R2014b, use [rgb2lab](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2lab.html) instead of `makecform` and `applycform`, as per [makecform doc](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/makecform.html?searchHighlight=makecform&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) itself :

```
lab = rgb2lab(L);
```

that may solve your problem as I think you did not apply the transformation to the right image. The image with no green (`L`) is not used as `L` is used to store the transformation data on the next line. The transformation is then applied to `I` and not `L` as it no longer exists.

That being said, your code computes the mean values on the entire image, not only the materials part as the background is blacked and not removed. If you want the mean values of the materials only, you may do the following :

```
I=imread('006.jpg');   %import image
I=double(I)./255;   %convert to double
I=imresize(I,0.25);    %resize image
%convert rgb to lab
lab=rgb2lab(I);
%separate l, a, b values
l=lab(:,:,1);
a=lab(:,:,2);
b=lab(:,:,3);
%calculate mean values
G=I(:,:2)-I(:,:,1)-I(:,:,3);   %how green(2) compared to red(1) and blue(3)
I_materials = G < 0; % is materials 0/1
lm=mean(l(I_materials));
am=mean(a(I_materials));
bm=mean(b(I_materials));
```

Comment: your solution was great, thanks. I use MATLAB > R2015b. Can you explain more about what the difference between using `rgb2lab` instead of `makecform` and `applycform`?

Comment: I could not really tell the difference as i have never used any of those functions myself. I just quoted the documentation. Checking the documentation, I can tell you that the default reference white point is not the same (`d65` vs `icc)` and that there are a few more options available with `rgb2lab`. If my answer was ok, please accept it by clicking on the check mark in the left margin.